# Windows 7 - Recuva unable to find files

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My family computer had some important documents on the desktop. Not being the main user of the computer I am unable to know exactly what happened but a less advanced user imported photos onto the desktop which filled the screen and they then deleted each one(most likely the documents too) Whether these were originally shortcuts or not; they are now.

Clicking on them gives the error message "shortcut refers to has been changed or moved" Searching through the drives I have been unable to find the files. I have downloaded a portable version of Recuva and ran it on the drive and it has been unable to find any deleted documents.

I posted on a computer help forum and was sent to this site: http://support.microsoft.com/mats/system_maintenance_for_windows/en-us I ran it and it said it had fixed the problem but unfortunately it had only deleted the shortcuts and not recovered or found the files and documents.

Is there anything else I can try as I have used Recuva before and had a 100% success rate until now and really need these documents as they are very important. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

*note*
The documents lost were Microsoft Works documents not word and folders
Nothing has been installed since losing them

Comment: Unless you ran Recuva right after these files were deleted its entirely possible the files are simply gone.  You are not even sure the reason the shortcuts exist or if they were shortcuts to the images.  Its entirely possible the original files still exist.  Have you looked for a file connected to a single shortcut to verify the location of the file?  Its not clear what you want, if Recuva is failing to restore the files, other recovery software won't have any luck recovery software is recovery software. although you could use Spinrite , it has the ability, to restore files at times

Comment: This is probably a no, but did you have File History turned on? You can see if there was an image made of the folder by going to `C:/Users/YouUserName` and right-clicking Desktop, then clicking Properties. There may be some previous versions of the folder in the `Previous Versions` tab.

Comment: The Computer has been unaltered since the problem occurred and yes I have looked for a file connected to a single shortcut and have been unable to find the location. Will try Spinrite now

Comment: @sam_7_h - Unless the computer has been off this entire time its not possible for it to be 100% unaltered

Comment: Agreed, however there were over 30 documents. How likely is it that they have all already been overwritten through having the computer on and searching for them? Seems unlikely that I would find no trace at all